# Not able to convert string to Int for summing

Tags: java, android-studio

I have the following code in Android Studio.

```
public void addTotal() {
    String sub1 = subtotal1.getText().toString();
    String newSub1 = sub1.replace("$", "");
    String sub2 = subtotal2.getText().toString();
    String newSub2 = sub2.replace("$", "");
    String sub3 = subtotal3.getText().toString();
    String newSub3 = sub3.replace("$", "");

    totalAmt.setText(newSub1 + newSub2 + newSub3);
}
```

I have not been able to add them as integer. Am I missing anything?

`subtotal1`, `subtotal2`, `subtotal3` are `TextView` in the app.

Comment: yes, you are forgetting to parse them to actual ints. what you are doing is String concatenation, not a mathematical '+'

Comment: I have tried most of the methods i found, but none seems to be able to work for me. App is able to run, until i tried to add and display the total. Guess maybe it's some errors in other parts of my codes.

Comment: you are unclear of what you get as result, but the description I gave you, and Tim's answer already solve a major issue in your code. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text dollar amounts might have a decimal component, you may use `Double#parseDouble` here:

```java
public void addTotal() {
    String sub1 = subtotal1.getText().replace("$", "");
    String sub2 = subtotal2.getText().replace("$", "");
    String sub3 = subtotal3.getText().replace("$", "");

    Double total = Double.parseDouble(sub1) + Double.parseDouble(sub2) +
                   Double.parseDouble(sub3);
    totalAmt.setText("$" + String.valueOf(total));
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seems to work for me too. Really don't know what's wrong, maybe it's other parts of my codes